# what is required in following function code[what]

Tags: javascript

```
function areBothTrue(bool1, bool2) {

}

console.log(areBothTrue(true, false), '<-- should be false');
console.log(areBothTrue(true, true), '<-- should be true');
```

Comment: This question is relatively incomplete. Please read [ask] to learn how to improve your question. Either way, I recommend to have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra .

Answer (score 0):

```
function areBothTrue(bool1, bool2) {
  return bool1 && bool2;
}
```